# Html to csv with rowspan and colspan using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, csv

Are there any ways to export html table with rowspan and colspan to csv or xls ??? I have tried finding solutions, but I don't get a working one.
[image]

Comment: CSV and XLS are not meant to be used for layout. If you need to keep this kind of table format, you might be better off looking at an export to PDF / Word / ...

Comment: actually, the pic above is the pdf that i export with json data.